# How to get a list of permissions for a token?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

There is an access token to Instagram API. How can I get a list of rights that he has? For example basic, public_content, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need scopes for a specific token, like for debugging or something, you could use this [Instagram token generator tool](https://instagramtoken.com).

Every token has `basic` scope automatically. Just select every scope option and on the following screen make sure to log in as the same user the originally authorized the token, whichever scopes ARE NOT listed when it asks you to authorize... **those** are the scopes your token already has. The reason this works is because Instagram will only ask you to authorize the scopes that you have not already granted.